# JS button to hit specific URL in browsing history

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bigcommerce

I'm working on an  e-commerce site. I want to add a "continue shopping" button to the cart page, but the shop has multiple types of items. If they added fabric to their cart, it would take them back to the main fabric page, and if they added notions to the cart, it would take them back to the main notions page. The problem is, that while the main fabric and notions pages have "/fabric" and "/notions" in the URL, the products do not. So when I go to the fabric section, choose a print, the URL for the print won't say "/fabric" in the URL. And since there is a sidebar menu, I can't always guarantee that the main category page will be the 2nd page back in their history. Is there a way to generate a button that will search through their history and connect them to either "/fabric" or "/notions" depending on which they visited most recently?

Edit: I'm looking to do something like this: https://papathemes.com/bigcommerce-add-button-to-go-back-the-last-visited-category-page-on-shopping-cart/

Comment: Can you add some of your code?

Comment: @PraveenAlluri I'm working on adding a button that doesn't exist yet, and the code for the rest of the site seems irrelevant. Is there specific code it would help you to see?

Comment: I don't completely understand, but I notice you're using PHP. Could this be solved by storing the page info and URLs into PHP's $_SESSION so you can keep track of every page and URL visited?

Comment: @TomMcPadden Possibly - I'm not as familiar with PHP, I tagged it because I figured it could be a potential solution but I'm not really familiar enough to know how to do what you're suggesting. I'll be looking into it though!

Comment: In that case I would strongly recommend experimenting with PHP's $_SESSION, it can store variables and arrays from page to page, I think that's the solution here. Good luck.

Comment: The description of the tag `history` starts with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" (yes, in CAPITALS for CLARITY). So don't use it.

Comment: Don’t use the history for this, but link to the appropriate URL. In your server-side coding, get the details for the product that was added, and check which category it belongs to. Then output a link that contains the URL for that category overview page in its href attribute.